# video sequence editor exports two black and white images for a few frames

Tags: export, video-sequence-editor, video, stereoscopy

I am exporting a video to mp4, and a few frames of a clip get exported black and white, plus the frame is stretched into a square and duplicated, and all of it is smaller than the original frame size. It looks a little like stereoscopic gone wrong.

The strip has no filters, but the next strip is a fast-forwarded strip from the same clip.

Adding the previous frame, which is OK.

I tried re-inserting the clip, and the error now occurs for a different frame.

Also happens with other clips.

Sometimes, re-exporting helps, but I just can't get rid of this one.

[image: strange export]

[image: original]

I am on Windows 11 with Blender 3.6

Comment: can you share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com with a minimal setup, like delete as many frames as possible and still reproduce the same problem.